# error while installing log4cxx file

Tags: ros, log4cxx, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i am getting error while trying to install log4cxx file on my mac os x lion.
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34341/error-while-installing-log4cxx-file/) by [cibe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2410/cibe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try searching for log4cxx, there are solutions such as [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/29320/failed-to-install-log4cxx-homebrew-osx-1068/). See if that solves your problem. The search function fails of key words 3 characters or less so don't bother searching for *osx* but *lion* is another good one to include. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1